# How do I get Android string resources for flutter package?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to read the stings.xml file in another package.

I'm creating a flutter package

What should I do?

flutter example app string xml

```xml
  <string name="client_id">clientid</string>
```

flutter package

```
   context.getString(R.stirng.client_id); // not found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read it from Context after set it in xml file:

Add this class to your plugin:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.annotation.NonNull

class PluginUtilities 
{
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun getResourceFromContext(@NonNull context: Context, resName: String): String {
            val stringRes = context.resources.getIdentifier(resName, "string", context.packageName)
            if (stringRes == 0) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The 'R.string.%s' value it's not defined in your project's resources file.", resName))
            }
            return context.getString(stringRes)
        }

    }
}
```

Then when you need any string from resources, you can call getResourceFromContext method, for example i will get access_token from resources:

```
val accessToken: String = PluginUtilities.getResourceFromContext(context,"access_token")
```

I hope the answer is useful...

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to access `xml` file in `flutter` package

You can create a file `Strings.dart`

```
class Strings {
  static const String client_id = "xxxxxxxx";
}
```

And use it like this

```
Text(Strings.client_id, /*Code*/),
```

Don't forget to `import` Strings.dart

```
import '../Strings.dart';
```